# LEFT JOIN W/ FILTER

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use LEFT JOIN to produce a COUNT but I'm struggling on the format because I am using WHERE to filter out the count.  I need to WHERE on both of the tables.  Here is what I have

```
SELECT Count(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
FROM   [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL
               WHERE  oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
                      AND rL.[REJECT] = 0)
```

Once I add `AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43776'` to the mix, it produces a 0 count.  That value exists in the table and I've tried to rewrite this differently several times.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: And for the record, I did originally have the tables reversed so that the LEFT table was my ORDER_OPTICS table, but produced the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
FROM    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL
INNER JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL ON  oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
WHERE
rL.[REJECT] = 0  AND oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43775'
```

Comment: and what does it returns?

Comment: 0, if you remove oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] it produces a correct count.

Comment: ok if you remove rL.[REJECT] = 0 instead, what happens? and what is the type of oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]

Comment: If I remove the REJECT but leave the SO_LINE_NUMBER, I still get a zero.  The type is varchar(50) and the SO_LINE_NUMBER is in quotes.

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
FROM    [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL
INNER JOIN [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL ON  oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
WHERE
rL.[REJECT] = 0  AND LTRIM(RTRIM(oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER])) = '43776'

Comment: SELECT * FROM 
[ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] 
WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43776' does it reuturn anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133910/discussion-between-lotan-s-and-addohm).

Comment: `SELECT COUNT([SO_LINE_NUMBER]) FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43776'` produces a correct count as I would expect.

Comment: found the problem.  Somehow my system is pulling in the wrong line number.

Answer (score 0):

You should really be separating the conditions . . . one for the subquery and one in the outer query:

```
SELECT Count(rL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
FROM [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] rL
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM  [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] oL
              WHERE oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] AND
                    oL.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43776'
             ) AND
       rL.[REJECT] = 0;
```

However, I don't think this would be causing your particular problem.

Comment: My original code before I started trying to solve this issue did that.  `SELECT Count(oL.SERIAL_NUMBER)
FROM   [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_ORDER_OPTICS] AS oL
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   [ROBOTICS_OPTICS_UAT].[dbo].[AOF_OPTIC_RESULTS] AS rL
               WHERE  oL.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = rL.[SERIAL_NUMBER]
                      AND rL.[REJECT] = 0) AND oL.SO_LINE_NUMBER = 43776`